# C# try to use Visio Shape from a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, visio

I am Working with Visio and c# and I have a Problem with the shapes From Visio.

I provide a Dictionary with a String and an Visio Shape

```
SortedDictionary<string, Visio.Shape> DicShapes 
                       = new SortedDictionary<string, Visio.Shape>();

DicShapes.Add("Pos3", shape_Pos3);
```

So, if i am now try to use the Visio.Shape i got an COMExeption.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Visio.Shape> kvp2 in DicShapes) 
{
    if (kvp2.Key == "Pos3")
    {
        beginXCell.GlueToPos(kvp2.Value, 0.5, 1);
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to investigate the COM error first. What is it? Which line?

Comment: its by beginxCell and kvp2.value creats the error.

Comment: Are you sure you will be dealing with duplicate keys in your `SortedDictionary` or will your key *Pos3* rather be unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you stated that your keys will be unique I'd suggest

```
Visio.Shape selectedShape;

if (DicShapes.TryGetValue("Pos3", out selectedShape))
{
    beginXCell.GlueToPos(selectedShape, 0.5, 1);
}
```

instead of iterating over the whole `SortedDictionary`.

If you have to deal with non-unique keys you could extract the desired subset using a linq extension method:

```
var filtered = DicShapes.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == "Pos3");
```